# Double vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces

So I'm modelling a phone, and I'm making a little divot to separate the screen from the body. Before, I wasn't sure if I wanted to include this and after extruding the faces down, I decided to extrude them back up, only for me to extrude them back down again. The vertices ended up staying, however, and now I have two faces in the exact same spot. I want to get rid of one ring of faces, and I've tried merge by distance but I've had no luck with that. Is there anything I can do?

[image: Picture of Duplicate faces]

[image: Picture of Duplicate faces, different face selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge by distance should work just fine.
Try adjusting the distance value that pops up in the bottom left till it says removed X vertices at the bottom.